# How to migrate from HTTP/1.1 to HTTP/2 from SEO point of view?

Tags: nginx, https, seo, bots, http2

I'm aware that HTTP/2 is using only `https`.

My existing implementation are all HTTP/1.1 with `http` protocol for all the urls on the website.

To add HTTP/2 support, without change the html source code, I plan to redirect all `http` requests to `https` on the nginx server block level.

With this approach, is there any drawback/impact on search engine indexing and bot crawling?

Comment: It belongs to http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Many, many references for how to migrate from HTTP to HTTPS online so just Google this. Or ask/search at sister site of webmaster.stackexchange.com. Once on HTTPS there's no real difference in SEO terms to migrate from HTTP/1.1 to HTTP/2.

Basically it's that (set up redirect) but need to ensure HTTPS is set up correctly, that all resources on your page (e.g. external and internal URLs to load images, JS, CSS... etc.) are HTTPS, update sitemap, register HTTPS URL at Google Search Consle to keep an eye on errors. And then wait. You'll probably see an initial dip in search traffic but if you've done it right that should quickly recover.

Comment: Are you saying even external URLs not on my domain needs to be in `HTTPS`?  eg. What if remove image I'm linking to is only available in `HTTP`?

Comment: Links don't need to be HTTPS but resources used by your page (including images) need to be HTTPS or you'll get a mixed content error when someone load your page over HTTPS. If external image is not available over HTTPS then you need to either stop loading it on your page or load a local copy instead before you switch to HTTPS to avoid this error.

Comment: On Google search result, I notice that it's using HTTPS url (eg. `https://www.google.com/url?url=http://domain.com`) to wrap and redirect the HTTP urls.  Is it necessary?  Or as you said, links don't need to be HTTPS and I can simple put external links in standard HTTP?

Comment: That's done for a different reason - to protect the search terms (which are in the URL for the search results page) from being passed in the referrer field to the new website. This is because Google believes that search terms potentially contain sensitive or private information and therefore shouldn't be shared.